# How to read a NFC TagID and show it in outputtext component in Oracle MAF?

Tags: nfc, oracle-maf

I made an application that reads a tag NFC and all I try to do is launch a alert to display the TAG UID, but to deploy a device android, feel the sound of reading, but does not show anything I've seen many applications, unfortunately none that is Oracle MAF

The file nfc.amx is:

```
<![CDATA[    
<script type="text/javascript">     

    nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(
        function(nfcEvent){
             console.log(nfcEvent.tag.id);
        },
        function() {
             console.log("Listening for NFC tags.");
        },
        function() {
             console.log("NFC activation failed.");
        }
    );  
</script>
```

The Call to managed beans

```
<amx:commandButton text="Share" id="cb1" actionListener="#{nfc.onShare}"/>
```

The Bean is:

```
public void onShare(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    AdfmfContainerUtilities.invokeContainerJavaScriptFunction(
        AdfmfJavaUtilities.getFeatureId(),
        "nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener",
        new Object[] {"nfcEvent"}
    );
    //new Object[] { this.getUrl()});
}
```

Comment: do you read this https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/how_to_add_cordova_nfc ?

Comment: yes, i read this blogs, also add cordova nfc plugins y my project. if you made an application to read a nfc tag and that works, I would greatly appreciate it.